# Method keeps returning false when it should return true?

Tags: php, class, methods, return

I have a method that checks if a thumbnail is validate for uploading. For some reason it is returning false in the calling program.

The image file definitely meets the requirements that I set for it in terms of correct size, dimensions, file type and there are no errors in the file.

This is the `print_r()` of the Image file:

```
imageArray ( [file] => Array ( [name] => juliensbook2slide.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\php5A99.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 20590 ) )
```

Here is the method code:

```
public function checkThumb(){
        $this->temp_dir = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $this->image_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $this->image_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $this->image_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $this->image_error = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        @$this->image_dimensions = getimagesize($this->temp_dir);
        $this->image_width = $this->image_dimensions[0]; // Image width
        $this->image_height = $this->image_dimensions[1]; // Image height
        $this->path = '';
        $this->error = '';
        if(!empty($this->image_name) && $this->image_error == 0){

            $this->path = 'img/thumb_/'.$this->random_name. $_FILES['file']['name'];

            if(in_array($this->image_type, $this->allowed_type)){

                if($this->image_size <= $this->max_size){

                    if(($this->image_width < $this->max_width) && $this->image_height < $this->max_height){


                        return true;

                    }else{
                        return $error = 'ERROR: Image dimension must be no larger than 4050x4050';
                    }

                }else{
                    return $error = 'ERROR: Image size must be no larger than 5MB';
                }
            }else{
                return $error = 'ERROR: image must be .jpg, .gif, .png only.';
            }
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and here is the code where it is not moving the uploaded image because it is returning false:

```
if($register->checkThumb){
                //send image to permanent image directory
                $register->moveUploadedImage();

                //if the thumbnail failed validation put the error message in variable
            }else if(is_string($register->checkThumb())){
                $message = $register->checkThumb();

            }
                print_r($_FILES);
                //put record of user into database
                $register->convertSex();
                $register->insertIntoDB($thumb);
}
```

So why is it returning false?

Comment: I would also suggest not calling the method three times (first in the `if` and second in the `else if` and third in the assignment). Call it once and save the result in a variable to avoid running the same code 3 times needlessly.

Comment: Coul dyou give me an example of how your suggestion would look?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't calling the method. There were no round brackets after the method name. So basically you were checking if a property named checkThumb is set.

As in `$register->checkThumb` vs. `$register->checkThumb()`.

This should work:

```
if($register->checkThumb()){  //send image to permanent image directory
    $register->moveUploadedImage();
}  //if the thumbnail failed validation put the error message in variable
else if(is_string($register->checkThumb())) {
    $message = $register->checkThumb();
}
```

But i would recommend not calling the same method 3 times so I'd use the following:

```
$checked_thumb = $register->checkThumb();
if($checked_thumb){  //send image to permanent image directory
    $register->moveUploadedImage();
}  //if the thumbnail failed validation put the error message in variable
else if(is_string($checked_thumb)) {
    $message = $checked_thumb;
}
```